# Property 'title' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have this issue when working with React and TS - when mapping an array of the dummy values, one of the properties is always red. My code:

ProjectList.tsx

```
const DUMMY_PROJECTS = [
    {
        id: "p1",
        title: "My bug business",
        description: "A very cool and stinky one",
        image:
        "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/61/e3/55/61e3552467f1f697195b9ea9b07c9cd5.jpg",
    },
    {
        id: "p2",
        title: "My bug business",
        description: "A very cool and stinky one",
    image:
    "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/61/e3/55/61e3552467f1f697195b9ea9b07c9cd5.jpg",
},
];

const ProjectList = () => {
  return (
    <ul className={classes.project_display}>
      {DUMMY_PROJECTS.map((project) => {
        return <ProjectList
          key={project.id}
          title={project.title} //problematic 
          description={project.description}
          image={project.image}
        />;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

ProjectItem.tsx

```
interface ProjectProps {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
}

const ProjectItem:React.FC<ProjectProps> = (props:ProjectProps) => {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.image} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{props.title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>{props.description}</Card.Text>
        <Button variant="primary">Details</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

It throws this error: Type '{ key: string; title: string; description: string; image: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.   Property 'title' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

I tried to put type: any to all of the values but it didnt work out

Comment: You called `ProjectList` instead of `ProjectItem`.

Comment: Nooooo, I really did. Thank you, I never really checked this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called ProjectList instead of ProjectItem

Answer (score 0):

Try making DUMMY_PROJECTS of array of ProjectProps type

```
const DUMMY_PROJECTS: ProjectProps[] = [
    {
        id: "p1",
        title: "My bug business",
        description: "A very cool and stinky one",
        image:
        "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/61/e3/55/61e3552467f1f697195b9ea9b07c9cd5.jpg",
    },
    {
        id: "p2",
        title: "My bug business",
        description: "A very cool and stinky one",
    image:
    "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/61/e3/55/61e3552467f1f697195b9ea9b07c9cd5.jpg",
},
];
```

Comment: Nope still the same error